# Android full screen dialog fragment and collapsing toolbar issue

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-dialogfragment

I'm having trouble with showing a full screen dialog in an activity which contains a collapsing toolbar.  When I show the full screen dialog, the toolbar goes under the status bar instead of being below the status bar as shown below:

[image]

If I take away the collapsing toolbar (like in other activities I have), I don't have this problem.  The toolbar from the dialog shows perfectly below the status bar.  Here is my xml to for the activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.casillassportsapps.mytrackfieldteam.views.RosterDetailsActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/roster_details_app_bar_height"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/photoImageView"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/roster_details_image_size"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/roster_details_image_size"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:importantForAccessibility="no"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_account_circle_white"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/detailContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_assessment_white_24dp" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Is there anything wrong with the way I have my collapsing toolbar set up?

Comment: what is the support library version that you are using?

Comment: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Add `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` for both 
`AppBarLayout` and `CollapsingToolbarLayout`

Full Code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.casillassportsapps.mytrackfieldteam.views.RosterDetailsActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

          <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/photoImageView"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/roster_details_image_size"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/roster_details_image_size"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:importantForAccessibility="no"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_account_circle_white"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/detailContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_assessment_white_24dp" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I actually tried that before posting. :(

Comment: did u try adding ` android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` for the parallax Image

Comment: try adding  android:fitsSystemWindows="false" for me it worked

Comment: Or you can try adding  android:fitsSystemWindows="true" in android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout

Comment: @Michal_196 I changed android:fitsSystemWindows to false.  I'm still getting the same result.  I've also tried putting android:fitsSystemWindows = "true" int he appbarlayout.  Same result.

Answer (score 0):

Apply this style to your DialogFragment -

Style -

```
<style name="AppTheme.FullScreenDialogStyle" parent="AppTheme.YourParentTheme">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
</style>
```

DialogFragment Java -

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.AppTheme.AppTheme_FullScreenDialogStyle);
}
```

Refer [here](https://gist.github.com/koocbor/88db64192638bff09aa4)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method to show full screen with Navigation Bar or not

```
public static void makeActivityFullScreen(AppCompatActivity activity, boolean showNavigationBar) {

        Window window = activity.getWindow();


        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            if (showNavigationBar)
                window.setFlags(FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
            else
                window.setFlags(FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);

        } else
            window.setFlags(FLAG_FULLSCREEN, FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    }
```

and add this attr in your style

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
```